# Making my script double-click perform a task that requires sudo privileges

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mono, sudo

I have a very simple script, similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Select the directory where the file to run is located
cd '/home/vmi/Área de Trabalho/TesteComandosNoLinux'
#I run my software
mono my-program.exe
```

I found that I need my software to run as an administrator for some functionality to work properly.
Therefore, I need to replace:

```
mono my-program.exe
```

per:

```
sudo mono my-program.exe
```

This script runs [with two clicks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows) to make it as user-friendly as possible.

I would like to keep running with two clicks, but couldn't create (or find a script) like that.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt

Comment: This link also helped me. I go write my resolution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was edit the file /etc/sudoers

Add at end of file:

```
user ALL=(ALL) ALL
user ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:path/of/my/second/script.sh
user ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:path/of/mono
user ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:path/of/my/executable
```

User password is required to run my script with `./my-second-script.sh`.This does not happen when the script is executed with `sudo ./my-second-script.sh`, but I found no equivalent way to do `sudo ./my-second-script.sh` with two clicks.

The resolution was to create a script that calls my script that doesn't need a password when running the sudo command.

my-first-script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd /home/vmi/desktop/myfolder
sudo meu-segundo-Script.sh
```

my-second-script.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mono my-program.exe
```